# How to prevent different users to save same value for a field via ajax/c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-4.5

I have an aspx page receiving email address from the end user and having the ajax call below:

```
function IfEmailExists() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Handler.ashx",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { 'Email': $('#txtEmail').val(), 'Method': 'IfEmailExists' },
                    responseType: "json",
                    success: OnCompleteIfEmailExists,
                    error: OnFail
                });
                return false;
            }
```

The function below runs in Handler.ashx.cs after ajax part is triggered:

```
case "IfEmailExists":
  ss = new Staff();
  string Email = context.Request["Email"];
  string IsEmailExist = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(ss.CheckIfEmailExists(Email));

  context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
  context.Response.Write(IsEmailExist);
  return;
```

In Staff class, the function below is triggered via the code above:

```
public int CheckIfEmailExists(string Email)
{
   int outputEmail = 0;
   SQLDatabase sqldb = new SQLDatabase();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = sqldb.ExecStoredProcedureDataTable("[spDoesEmailExists]", new SQLParamList().Add("@Email", Email));
   if (dt.Rows.Count > 1)
   {
      outputEmail = 1;
   }
   else
   {
      outputEmail = 0;
   }
   return outputEmail;
}
```

[spDoesEmailExists] stored procedure does:

```
Select Email from StaffEmailUsage where Email = @Email
```

Please note that there is another ValidateEmail() function checks if the email is valid.

With the help of this structure, when a user tries to use an email address more than once, (s)he is receiving an error message saying: `This email address has been already used!` by default. I have tried to pass this, but I always received the error.

The problem is, I am seeing that different people have used the same email address more then once. How come is it possible I could not find. I tried using blank spaces at the beginning and ending of an email address, disabling javascript, using different browsers but I always received error message, which is expected. How can I prevent different users to use same email address multiple times? Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Add a UNIQUE index / constraint on the database.

Comment: When is this email check function triggered? If it validates the e-mail after leaving the e-mail address field, and user continues to fill the form and submits the form later, then using the same e-mail addresses are possible, if you do not check it again just before creating the db record. Another possibility is changing the e-mail address later by editing the account, if there is such a function.

Comment: Your `$.ajax` request expects `json` response but your handler function set `ContentType="text/html"`. Also check raw response from the server.

Comment: Hmmm, can it cause that issue? @AlexKudryashev

Comment: First test your stored procedure using existing and non-existing emails, next check response from Web server. *Side note: `sp` prefix is reserved for system SPs*.

Comment: Sp works fine, tried with different emails and always received expected result. Will check response of web server, but i don't know what i am expecting to see there, since i am not able to perform the issue, i could not manage to save two different records belonging to different users but same email. @AlexKudryashev

Comment: For test purpose, rewrite your `case` like  this: `string IsEmailExist = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(1);//or 0` to see the result.

Comment: Your `sp` always returns exactly **1** (one) row.

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo @AlexKudryashev thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

Adding unique constraint on the Email column in the `StaffEmailUsage` table will prevent duplicate emails from being saved to the database. With this constraint, any time the application tries to save a duplicate email, there will be a sql error, which will likely expose where or how users bypassing the error message.

```
ALTER TABLE StaffEmailUsage
ADD UNIQUE (Email)
```

Relying on errors to find the source of the problem may not be ideal. Double check that every place a user can create or update an email, the validation is in place.

Note: If there are duplicates in the table you will not be able to add the unique constraint until the duplicates are resolved. To find the rows that need to be fixed you can run this query:

```
SELECT Email, COUNT(Email) 
FROM StaffEmailUsage
GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(Email) > 1
```

Comment: The table has been created years ago, there are many multiple emails, so altering the email field in the table might not be a good idea for this case:(

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43823/can-i-add-a-unique-constraint-that-ignores-existing-violations @ErayBalkanli